# maven3 multi module child groupId

Tags: maven-3, pom.xml, multi-module

In maven3, I get warnings if I specify the groupId of a child module in a multi-module project to be the same as the parent module. Now I'm not sure if this is indicating that I should use a different groupId or if I should omit it to use the parent groupId.

According to http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-naming-conventions.html

*A good way to determine the granularity of the groupId is to use the project structure. That is, if the current project is a multiple module project, it should append a new identifier to the parent's groupId.
eg. org.apache.maven, org.apache.maven.plugins, org.apache.maven.reporting*

That leads me to believe that each child should have a different groupId than the parent. Is that correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [maven documentation](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html)

> If we want the groupId and / or the version of your modules to be the
>   same as their parents, you can remove the groupId and / or the version
>   identity of your module in its POM. This allows the module to inherit
>   the groupId and / or the version of its parent POM.

The warning is to let the user know this and avoid situations like misspelling `groupId` or `versionId`.

Comment: So would you recommend omitting the groupid in the child and inheriting from the parent or using a different groupid?

Comment: @JeffStorey. The former, unless you have any special need for the latter.